# Loops inside functions in r

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm having trouble in setting up loops. I want to create a function that have several arguments and one of the argument is a vector, and for each value in that vector it must truncate an infinite series and give me the **sum**.

**My code is like this**:

```
zt<-function(t,p,e){for (i in t){v=0;j=0
    repeat{v=v0;v=v+(i^j/factorial(j)^p)
    if (v-v0 < e) break else j<-j+1}}
    return(v)}

t=c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8);zt(t,0.5,0.00005)
```

It only returns the last value in `t` and yet `i` want for each value in `t`.

Comment: Argument `v0` is missing in the function.

Comment: What is the point of having these two commands `v=v0;v=v+(i^j/factorial(j)^p)` in the `repeat` loop? Plus, are you sure it will always reach the breaking condition?

Comment: I was focused on the code rather than the question: I'm pretty sure that the function you wrote does not "truncate" a series. Can you tell us a little bit more about the function in question?

Comment: Here is what I propose: (i) give us the expression of the function to approximate, (ii) propose an R function to compute this approximation given *one* value for `t`, (iii) try to use `Vectorize` on your R function to compute this approximation on a vector and (iv) update your question.

Comment: I want to find the sum from zero to infinite of 'n^j/(j!)^p' for specific value of p and n is a vector. Hope its now clear!!

Comment: Kind of. We have an answer to (i). Now let's try point (ii): remove this horrific `for (i in t)` loop and correct the erroneous line `v=v0` (it should be `v0=v`). Compare your result with function `exp` by setting `p` to 1. And update your question. If you show that you made efforts to try our recommendations, you will have quicker and more precise answers and comments.

Comment: Tried that and it gave warning messages that "the condition has length >1 and the first element is used" Am using my 'n=c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8)' and 'p=1' and have removed the loop and corrected 'v0=v' The full code am using is 'z<-function(n,p,e){v=0;j=0;repeat{v0=v;v=v+(n^j/factorial(j)^p);if (v-v0 < e) break else j<-j+1};return(v)};n=c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8);z(n,1,0.00005)'

Comment: Edit your question to update the example.

Comment: Your error is perfectly normal, this function can be applied to a scalar only. `z(2, 1, 1e-16)` is now a very good approximation for e².

Comment: To apply it to a vector, try `Vectorize`. (see point (iii) of my previous comment).

Comment: Thanks Vincent,it  worked well.